# Python3 mock: assert_has_calls for production-code methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

I've got this production class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def foo(self):
        # work with self.value here
        # raise RuntimeError("error!")
        return "a"
```

Which is being used from another place, like this:

```
class Caller:
    def bar(self, smth):
        obj = MyClass()
        obj.set_value(smth)
        # ...
        # try:
        obj.foo()
        # except MyError:
        #     pass

        obj.set_value("str2")
        # obj.foo()
```

and I got this:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    pass
```

In my test I want to make sure that Caller.bar calls obj.set_value, first with smth="a", then with smth="b", but I want it to really set the value (i.e. call the real set_value method). Is there any way for me to tell the mock to use the actual method, so I can later on read what it was called with?

P.S. I know that I can just change "foo" to require the parameter "smth" so I could get rid of "set_value", but I want to know if there is another option than this.

---

Okay, so I have tried this in my test:

```
def test_caller(self):
     with patch('fullpath.to.MyClass', autospec=MyClass) as mock:
         mock.foo.side_effect = [MyError("msg"), "text"]

         caller = Caller()
         caller.bar("str1")

         calls = [call("str1"), call("str2")]
         mock.set_value.assert_has_calls(calls)
```

But I see that the mock was not successful since the real "foo" is called when I wanted it to first raise MyError, then return "text".

Also, the assertion fails:

```
AssertionError: Calls not found.
Expected: [call('str1'), call('str2')]
Actual: []
```

Comment: Have you read through the mock and unittest docs? This is definitely doable. There are several examples on SO about this as well. Do you have any unittest code you can share as well to help with difficulties you are having?

Comment: I'm still with the tab open looking through it, but all I see is calls on 'called with' for mocks. And if I use "with patch.object(MyClass, 'set_value') as mock_fetch:", the mock_fetch will... well, replace my method.

Comment: That's not very helpful. Please modify your question and provide a [mcve] of your unittest code.

Comment: But if you are testing `Caller`, you are not testing `MyClass`. Are you *sure* you can't just mock out `MyClass` entirely?

Comment: This might be a good idea... I'm quite new to python, and quite new to python's mocks also... if I just use a MagicMock for MyClass, then I should be able to call my_magic_mock.set_value.assert_has_calls(). That should cleanse my test code from so many "with patch(...)"-es.

Comment: @Feoggou Try it out, and update your question with your code if you are having difficulties. Look up things like mocking a class, mocking an instance of a class. Things like that. Look at those examples and you will see how you can relate it to your situation. Try it out, and come back with your code. Good luck.

Comment: The fact is that when "mocking a class", as read from the tutorial, you have no control over the kind of class is being created by your SUT (here, the Caller instantiates an object of type MyClass, not one of type Mock). What I need is both a way to override some instance methods, and to check that other (real) instance methods were called.

Comment: @Feoggou You don't need that lambda from your `side_effect`. That was a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have mocked out your `Class`, and are not properly using the *instance* of your class. This is why things are not behaving as expected.

So, lets take a look at what is going on.

Right here:

```
with patch('fullpath.to.MyClass', autospec=MyClass) as mock:
```

So, what you are doing right here is mocking out your class `MyClass` only. So, when you are doing this:

```
mock.set_value.assert_has_calls(calls)
```

And inspect what is going on when you execute your unittest, your `mock` calls will actually contain this:

```
[call().set_value('str1'), call().foo(), call().set_value('str2')]
```

Pay attention to `call` as it is written as `call()`. `call` is with reference to your `mock` here. So, with that in mind, you need to use the *called* (aka `return_value` within context of the mocking world) `mock` to properly reference your mock object that you are trying to test with. The quick way to fix this is simply use `mock()`. So you would just need to change to this:

```
mock().set_value.assert_has_calls(calls)
```

However, to be more explicit on what you are doing, you can state that you are actually using the result of calling `mock`. Furthermore, it would actually be good to note to use a more explicit name, other than `mock`. Try `MyClassMock`, which in turn you name your instance `my_class_mock_obj`:

```
my_class_mock_obj = MyClassMock.return_value
```

So in your unit test it is more explicit that you are using a mocked object of your class. Also, it is always best to set up all your mocking before you make your method call, and for your `foo.side_effect` ensure that you are also using the *instance* mock object. Based on your recent update with your exception handling, keep your try/except without comments. Putting this all together, you have:

```
def test_caller(self):
    with patch('tests.test_dummy.MyClass', autospec=MyClass) as MyClassMock:
        my_class_mock_obj = MyClassMock.return_value
        my_class_mock_obj.foo.side_effect = [MyError("msg"), "text"]

        caller = Caller()
        caller.bar("str1")

        calls = [call("str1"), call("str2")]

        my_class_mock_obj.set_value.assert_has_calls(calls)
```

Comment: Have you tried it to see if it works? First, "mock.foo.side_effect = "  has no effect to me. Second, assert_has_calls still fails to me. It might be the fact that "MyClassMock.return_value" actually _instantiates_ an object there, a different object that what the Caller instantiates.

Comment: Fully tested. That works. Try it out. But the important thing here is understanding why your implementation did not work. Was it clear? @Feoggou

Comment: @Feoggou Is the code you provided in your question the EXACT same code? Because I pretty much copied your samples and got it working. If you have different code, you can't really fault my answer here. Furthermore, the fundamental concept of why it is not working is in the answer. So if you have different code, use my explanation as a guide to figure out what is going on, or update your answer to make things more clear.

Comment: Your unittest is not even testing what is happening with `mock.foo.side_effect = [MyError("msg"), "text"]`. Furthermore, in the sample you provided you are only calling `foo` once.

Comment: I have copied this test example you have shown here (except that I renamed "mock.foo.side_effect" -> "MyClassMock.foo.side_effect". The other classes are the same. It should have risen exception MyError.

Comment: @Feoggou Investigating

Comment: I now added commented out code for the calls that should make it work: a try-except for the first call to foo, and a second call to foo. I just saw them as not useful details, since I couldn't get the code to raise that exception anyway.

Comment: @Feoggou OK. I know what happened. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: Furthermore be careful with that `MyError`. I created a custom exception class to match that class you are calling and it fails the unittest. I simply changed that `MyError` to something generic like "adfasdf" and the unittest worked perfectly fine. Let me know.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I can't understand how it works to you. Try changing MyClass.foo to raise a RuntimeError or something, this should prove that the original foo is not called. In my case, the original foo is called. Also, look on my updated post for the commented out code that should catch MyError.

Comment: @Feoggou Look at another update based on the new code you provided. This works.

Comment: Not to me. What version of python are you using? And, are you sure your Caller.bar method instantiates an object of MyClass ("obj = MyClass()")? And are you sure it uses that object for the calls?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5 to test this. What editor are you using? Because if you use a debugger and trace the code you will see what is happening. I traced the code to see what was going on.

Comment: Python3.5, PyCharm. I don't use the debugger.

Comment: I urge you to get used to using the debugger. It is a powerful tool. It will show you everything you are trying to figure out.

Comment: btw, from what I read, a statement such as "my_class_mock_obj = MyClassMock.return_value" I understood as "Instantiate an object of class represented by MyClassMock" --- so that all further operations on the class object my_class_mock_obj operate solely on that instance of the class. How can this return_value influence all instantiations of the class?

Comment: What do you mean by influence all instantiations of the class? What class are we talking about?

Comment: The class Caller I am testing is instantiating an object of class MyClass -- this MyClass is the one I am talking about. I can't see how the "my_class_mock_obj = MyClassMock.return_value" in the test can influence the instance of MyClass created in the Caller.bar.

Comment: You are mocking MyClass with a patch decorator. When you instantiate an instance of MyClass, how are you going to access that instance from your mock? It certainly will not be via `MyClassMock`. It will most definitely be via `MyClassMock.return_value`. The *return value* of calling *something*. That *something* is `MyClassMock`. And that `MyClassMock` is the patch of `MyClass`.

Comment: I do not understand your question, and I'm not sure you understood what I said. The class Caller is the production class I am testing, so I _cannot_ use a mock inside of it, because I _cannot_ use mocks inside production code.

Comment: I did not say to use a mock inside the `Caller` class. We are talking about your test method? The method you provided in your question that is using mock patch. No where did I suggest to use mock inside `Caller`.

Comment: Are you sure your Caller class looks the same (more or less the # lines) as the one I had posted?

Comment: @Feoggou conclusion? You don't need the `lambda`. Add your try/except and it will work. Mistake on my part. It is unnecessary.

Comment: @Feoggou Based on your recent update to your question. I don't see why doing what you did is the only way you can get it working. Here are the pastebins of the latest code (without the lambda). Each pastebin is actually in its own file. [real](http://pastebin.com/3XJUiXwN) and [test](http://pastebin.com/P5FTZaUT)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108056/discussion-between-idjaw-and-feoggou).

Comment: strange... your example works... as long as you keep the production classes in a different file than the test. In my simplified version (there where I was using "foo"-s and "bar"-s instead of real names) I had both production classes and test class in the same test file. And in this case, for some strange reason, mocking doesn't work for all instances of the class.

Comment: It would always be best to actually keep production classes different from test at all times. All tests should be in a separate folder away from any production code. When it comes to moving stuff to different files, you need to make sure that your patch is set to the location of where that class is. You are testing with respect to what you are testing.

Comment: If you are testing Caller and Caller is here: 'this.is.Caller'. Then you want to Mock `MyClass` from the `this.is.Caller` location because THAT is where you are doing your testing and your mocking should be with respect to that.

Comment: I know. I used a simplified version, which I had put in one single file, because it was easier for me to work / test on it isolated that way. Anyway, back to my _real_ case, where I use <package>/src/production_file_name.py and <package>/tests/test_file_name.py it still doesn't work --- the real instance method is used instead of the mock one. There's no error in patch - as not finding the class to Mock (the path is correct, and if I alter it to smth incorrect, then python yields an error). I'm investigating now, perhaps I'll get to something.

Comment: @Feoggou Your question has mutated in different things since you started your question. I suggest removing the last part of your question, that indicates it works based on where you are calling your code from, closing this question off (you can accept this answer if you wish to indicate it as helpful, which helps other readers as well) and start a new question about the fact that you can't call your unittests due to path issues.

Comment: I have created a new question. Thanks for the help & explanations :)